# How to duplicate values based on an variable

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

So for background, my company is running a contest. The number of units a customer has purchased determines how many entries they get into the contest.

The data partner we have to provide the list to wants a list of all account numbers with duplicated values to determine how many entries a person has.

So basically, I have a dataset that has ACCOUNT_NBR and UNITS.
If a Customer 12345 has 6 units, I want their account number to be in the final dataset 6 times.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, will happily clarify if needed.

Comment: Please present a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT account_nbr
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= t.units
       )
```

Before Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT account_nbr
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= t.units
           ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (account_nbr, units) AS
SELECT 1111, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2222, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3333, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4444, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | ACCOUNT_NBR |
> | --- |
> | 1111 |
> | 1111 |
> | 1111 |
> | 2222 |
> | 3333 |
> | 3333 |
> | 3333 |
> | 3333 |
> | 4444 |
> | 4444 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3dc9907c9a09b2620ab2d3b7645798e1)*